# Android SQLiteException. Why does it happen?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

This is the code for getting the table **RECORD** from the `SQLiteDatebase`. In the `try block` something goes wrong and it always throws the `SQLiteException`. All I am trying to do here is to convert each row of the table "RECORD" into a string and add it to an `ArrayList`, subsequently connect the array to the `ArrayAdapter`, and finally use `ListView` to display the array.

```
package com.example.tommy.stop_watch_real;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecordList extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_record_list);
        ListView temp = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recordList);
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

        **try {
            SQLiteOpenHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = dataBaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query("RECORD", new String[] {"_id, DATE, MINUTES"}, null, null,null,null,null);
            while (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                String id = Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(0));
                String date = cursor.getString(1);
                String minutes = Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(2));
                String finalValue = id + "|" + date + "|" + minutes;
                arrayList.add(finalValue);
            }
            adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    arrayList);
            temp.setAdapter(adapter);
            cursor.close();
            db.close();}**
            catch (SQLiteException e) {
                Toast.makeText(RecordList.this, "Database not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the code for my datebaseHelper:

```
class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "Record"; // name of the database
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1; //Version

    DataBaseHelper (Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE RECORD ("
                + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCERMENT, "
                + "DATE STRING," //careful
                + "MINUTES INTEGER" + ");"
        );
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    //no need to worry about this yet.
    }
}
```

The `toast` always shows up, meaning something is wrong in the `try block`. I just started android development a week ago and I don't know what went wrong in my code. It would be great if you could give me some direction.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: direction No 1 : read exception message

Comment: post stacktrace

Comment: In your `DBHelper` class Date has type **STRING**?How's that. Check this out:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-types.html

Comment: Thank you so much @JacekCz . I checked the exception message and I realised it was caused by the typo "AUTOINCERMENT". Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @Mandy8055 Hi. I converted the Dates into strings using "Date date = new Date();" and "String tempDate = date.toString();" in another activity. ^^

Comment: Does the error gets rectified?

Comment: @Mandy8055 No something still goes wrong and I have no idea what is happening. As soon as I start the activity the screen goes completely back... :( There must be some problem with the database...

Comment: What changes have you made till now?

Comment: @Mandy8055 Hi. Thank you so much for your comment :). It actually works now. I just made a mistake by using while(moveToFirst).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part seems wrong to me.

```
 while (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            String id = Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(0));
            String date = cursor.getString(1);
            String minutes = Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(2));
            String finalValue = id + "|" + date + "|" + minutes;
            arrayList.add(finalValue);
        }
```

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but the right way to get data from data base is like this:

```
 cursor.moveToFirst()
 while (cursor.isAfterLast()){
            String id = Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(0));
            String date = cursor.getString(1);
            String minutes = Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(2));
            String finalValue = id + "|" + date + "|" + minutes;
            arrayList.add(finalValue);
        }
```

Comment: Ahh!!!! I am trying to read all the records and convert each row into a string. I should have first used moveToFirst and then while(moveToNext). Thank you so much :). It finally works now.